# Changing abbrv.bst to sort first by year then by authors

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

As the title says - I'd like to change `abbrv.bst` so that references are first sorted by year (irrespective of authors) followed by authors, resulting in something like:

> [1] Jones, A., A paper, 2010.
>
> [2] Jones, A., A 2nd paper, 2011.
>
> [3] Jones, A., and Smith, B., a 3rd paper 2011.
>
> [4] Jones, A., A 4th paper, 2012.

`abbrv.bst` sorts by authors & then by year.

**I don't want to use the `biblatex` package** to avoid complications when sending the source files to publishers.